# Mechanics question...

Tags: classical-mechanics

Particles P and Q are attached to opposite ends of a light in-extensible string. P is at rest on a rough horizontal table. The string passes over a small smooth pulley which is ﬁxed at the edge of the table.Q hangs vertically below the pulley (see diagram). The force exerted on the string by the pulley has magnitude $4\sqrt{2}\,\rm N$. The coefficient of friction between P and the table is $0.8$.

(i) Show that the tension in the string is $4\,\rm N$ and state the mass of Q.
[image]

Comment: If anything's still unclear, please draw a [free body diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_body_diagram) focusing only on the pulley, and post it with the question. Chances are that all your problems and their resolutions are reflected in that free body diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizontal force on $P$ due to string balancing is the force of [static friction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Coefficient_of_friction) given by $$f=\mu\cdot F_n,$$  here $F_n=mg$ where $g$ is acceleration due to gravity and $m$ is the mass of $P$.
Let the tension be $T$ in the string. Now $|T|=|f_P|=|f_Q|$ where $f_P,f_Q$ are forces on $P$ and $Q$ by the string.
`Now the force on by the pulley upon the string = Tension in the vertical part of the string+Tension in the horizontal part`
So $4\sqrt2= \sqrt{T^2+T^2}=\sqrt2 T\implies T=4N$ since the angle between the vertical and horizontal portion is $90^0$. The mass of $Q$ is $\dfrac{4}{g}=\dfrac{4}{9.8} kg$. Similarly mass of $P$ can be found.

Comment: sorry but i don't get how to find the tension...

Comment: @Salma see my edit.

Comment: oooooooooohh... how didn't I think in it in this QUITE SIMPLE way.I got it ;)

Comment: I'd like to know the reason of downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Try to convince yourself that the free body diagram below is correct.

- $T \to$tension of the string
- $R_1 \to$Force exerted by the pulley on the string ($4\sqrt2N$ given)
- $R \to$Normal reaction force on $P$ by the table
- $\mu R \to$Static friction working on $P$

Here $\theta=45^{\circ}$

[image: Free Body Diagram]

So for the following 3 systems we've got 4 equilibrium:

\begin{align}
&\text{Pulley:}&R_1&=2T\cos\theta\tag{i}\\
&\text{Ball Q:}&T&=m_qg\tag{ii}\\
&\text{Ball P:}&T&=\mu R\tag{iii}\\
&\text{Ball P:}&R&=m_pg\tag{iv}\\
\end{align}

From $(i)$ we get :
$$4\sqrt2=2T\cos(45^{\circ}) = \frac{2T}{\sqrt2}\\
\therefore T=4N$$
From $(ii)$ we get :
$$T=m_qg=10m_q(\mathrm{taking}\ \ g=10m/s^2)\\
\therefore m_q=\frac{T}{10}=\frac{4}{10}=0.4kg$$

Comment: How to make such a fine diagram? Is there some software for this?

Comment: @Anupam google drawing :)